# How to force Laravel API to always return JSON, no redirects

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication, laravel-sanctum, laravel-fortify

I have a Laravel application that I've built to act only as a JSON API. It has no views, and acts only to support our 1st party SPA. It uses Laravel 8, Fortify, and Sanctum. My SPA lives at `my-app.test`, and the api at `api.my-app.test`. The SPA works as expected. However, if I visit one of my authenticated API routes in the browser, e.g. `api.my-app.test/someResource`, I get an error page telling me "Route [login] not defined.", and the stack trace reveals this code:

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php:393`

```php
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
  return $request->expectsJson()
    ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
    : redirect()->guest($exception->redirectTo() ?? route('login'));
}
```

I have the following file where I've tried to override the `redirectTo` and `unauthenticated` methods, but it doesn't work:
`app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`

```php
protected function unauthenticated($request, array $guards): JsonResponse
{
  return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
}

protected function redirectTo($request)
{
  return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

When I implement `unauthenticated` above, it seems it no longer authenticates any of my routes, hitting any API endpoint returns results that should be guarded. When I implement `redirectTo` above, I get another error saying "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected" and I'm not sure where to go from there.

What's the correct way to globally disable all views and redirects, and force Laravel to always return JSON? Is there a way to override `expectsJson`?

Answer (score 4):

Just handle the `AuthenticationException` in your `App\Exceptions\Handler`, like this:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        return response()->json(["error"=>30001, "message"=>"authenticate failed"]);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: If you are using a rest client like Postman to test, make sure you have the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers set to `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

This code will check the routes containing /api/* then it will return json data and for other routes (not containing /api/* ) will redirect to login page.

Put this code in app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```js
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $ex){

    if( $request->is('api/*') ) { // for routes starting with `/api`
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => $ex->getMessage()], 401);
    }

    return redirect('/login'); // for normal routes 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override `unauthenticated` function in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
}
```